# Combining FREQUENCY count and INNER CASE in SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join, oracle-apex, frequency

How do I combine both in order to show the student name (`sname`) and section number (`sectno`) for a class that has more than 6 student? So far I have this

```
SELECT student.sname, enroll.sectno,

FROM student

INNER JOIN enroll 

ON student.sid=enroll.sid
```

with

```
SELECT grade, 

COUNT(grade)AS Frequency

FROM enroll

GROUP BY grade

HAVING COUNT(grade)>6
```

Comment: What is the relation between `student` and `enroll` tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you were very close. I think the below should work for you:

```
SELECT 
student.sname, 
enroll.sectno,
COUNT(enroll.grade) AS Frequency
FROM student
INNER JOIN enroll ON student.sid=enroll.sid
GROUP BY student.sname, enroll.sectno
HAVING COUNT(enroll.grade)>6
```

Comment: I could not figure out where should I declare my COUNT variable. I've tried using the WHERE clause after declaring my INNER JOIN. Thank you for your time and help. This is very informative

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @S.Rain happy to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your 2md Select there's no relation to *a class that has more than 6 student*, IMHO the `GROUP BY` should be based on column like `classid`. And then you can simply combine both using a *Windowed Aggregate*:

```
with cte as
 (
   SELECT student.sname, enroll.sectno, 
      -- get the count per class, might be a different column than sectno
      count(*) over (partition by enroll.sectno) as cnt
   FROM student
   INNER JOIN enroll 
   ON student.sid=enroll.sid
 ) 
select * from cte
where cnt > 6
```

Comment: I see. I am very new with SQL itself so I never did thought to use the Partition By or using Windowed Aggregate. This is very helpful